# Вывод картинки через WALL.GET

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте программисты! Столкнулся с проблемой с VK API. Скрипт выводит все что мне надо, но вот с картинками беда, ни в какую ни хочет. Пробовал `<img src="<?=$user['photo']">`, но не получилось, буду рад помощи!

Вот, собственно, код:

```
<?
$params = [
  'owner_id' => '-Айди',
  'offset' => '0',
  'count' => '8',
  'filter' => 'all',
  'access_token' => 'токен',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'v' => '5.103' 
];
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?' . http_build_query($params);
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
?>
<?php foreach($response['response']['items'] as $user): ?>
<?php echo '<pre>',$user["text"], '</pre>' ?> <!--выводит текст -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

`"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":457239034,"album_id":-7,"owner_id":-183754119,"user_id":100,"sizes":[{"type":"m","url":"https:\/\/sun9-34.userapi.com\/c858520\/v858520624\/140478\/--gbrVqeZt4.jpg","width":130,"height":73},`

Вот самое начало, и, видимо, да, надо создать цикл, но как?

Comment: Для каких целей вы пишите на каждый пук и чих `<?php` ? И да, пробовали смотреть, что возвращает `var_dump($response);` ? Это желательно добавить в свой вопрос.

Comment: Не знаю, привык :D А $responsive выводит ссылку на картинку и все остальное.

Comment: @And "Для каких целей вы пишите на каждый пук и чих <?php" --- вообще-то это синтаксис управляющих конструкций в шаблоне. ну так, к слову, если вы не знали (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: **Мне так легче выделять в дивы и прописывать стили**

Comment: @Flames это нормальный синтаксис в шаблоне. Единственное, для вывода можно использовать `<?= $test; ?>` вместо `<?php echo $test; ?>`

Comment: @Сергей Мишин, ладно, хорошо. Сможете помочь с моей проблемой?

Comment: можно более полный код? именно с проблемной частью в том числе? и например получаемый ответ от вк приложить

Comment: {"type":"p","url":"https:\/\/sun9-50.userapi.com\/c858520\/v858520624\/14047d\/wqIRp-7JsfQ.jpg","width":200,"height":133}
Пример одного упоминания картинки из запроса

Comment: Пробовал сделать таким образом: `<img src="<?php echo $user["photo"] ?>">`, но также безуспешно

Comment: два вопроса: 1) где в приведенном вами ответе ключ "photo" и 2) какая в целом ошибка с картинкой? в  чём именно проблема заключается? Может вам там по attachments надо цикл делать? не?

Comment: Ну вот и ответ))) цикл внутри цикла нужен))

Comment: @СергейМишин, Это не нормально, это извращение называется.  И если вы не знали, это ооочень плохая практика такая мешанинка. За такое руки надо по плечи рубить.

Comment: @And учите  матчасть и тему шаблонизации в частности. Всего доброго.

Comment: @СергейМишин, Вам [суда](http://govnokod.ru/), сударь. А так о наш мего-мозг, вам за правило: `это НЕ удобно, это НЕ юзабельно, это противоречит ВСЕМ основным принципам программирования, это НИКТО не будет поддерживать, это быдлокод`.

Comment: @And да, пожалуй стоит разработчикам Yii2, Zend Framework, CakePHP и всем, кто использует эти фреймворки сказать, что это не удобно, не юзабельно и противоречит всему и вся, а то парни-то не знают

Comment: Я всего лишь задал вопрос....